# Rails 7 server does not start when using AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to upgrade our rails 5 codebase to rails 7. Everything works fine locally as well as on a standalone EC2 instance, but when I deploy to elastic beanstalk, the server get's stuck on `rdb` after deployment. The following are the logs.

```bash
Puma starting in single mode...
Jun 21 11:25:08 ip-172-31-23-186 web: * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 2.7.6-p219) ("Birdie's Version")
Jun 21 11:25:08 ip-172-31-23-186 web: *  Min threads: 5
Jun 21 11:25:08 ip-172-31-23-186 web: *  Max threads: 5
Jun 21 11:25:08 ip-172-31-23-186 web: *  Environment: development
Jun 21 11:25:08 ip-172-31-23-186 web: *          PID: 22775
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:208: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
Jun 21 11:25:11 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:504: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
Jun 21 11:25:13 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/continuation.so: warning: callcc is obsolete; use Fiber instead
Jun 21 11:25:15 ip-172-31-23-186 web: (rdb:1) Debug.rb
Jun 21 11:25:15 ip-172-31-23-186 web: Emacs support available.
Jun 21 11:25:15 ip-172-31-23-186 web: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:47:        next unless (dep.groups & groups).any? && dep.should_include?
Jun 21 11:25:25 ip-172-31-23-186 web: (rdb:1) /var/app/current/config/application.rb:45:module AppName
```

Where AppName is the name of our App.
I even tried running `puma` locally but could not replicate this bug anywhere except Elastic Beanstalk

### Locally

- ruby = 2.7.6
- rails = 7.0.3

### Elastic Beanstalk

- AMI = Amazon Linux 2
- Platform = Ruby 2.7

Comment: what is in Debug.rb ?

Comment: It's actually not in our codebase. My guess is that it's from the new rails-debug.

Comment: can you add a `pp ENV` somewhere where the server starts up (like in config/initializers or something) or `set` if you have some sort of shell script that starts the server? Try setting your local environment to the settings on the server. I don't think Debug.rb is suppose to run. Emacs support looks suspicious too. You might have some debug flag on that is making the application exhibit odd behaviors.

Comment: I tried this, there wasn't anything out of the ordinary. For now we are running the server by commenting out rails-debug. But that's a hack at best, still trying to figure it out.